# Looking for software to mix up photo slideshows with up to two tracks of audio/include text, etc

Tags: presentations, multimedia

I've been messing around with Picasa and PowerPoint to create brief, 1-4 minute slideshows with text slides, images, and a music background.

I'd like to take that one small step forward and have two tracks (one music, one vocal), and do some more fancy things with the text/slides.

What's the simplest tool for the job? My goal would be to publish something on either YouTube, in Flash, or in MOV format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerPoint 2007:

1. Use "Slide Show -> Record Narrations" to record your vocals on each slide.
2. Go to the first slide, and then "Insert -> Sound", and pick your background music file. Details here: http://www.ehow.com/how_2044906_add-background-music-powerpoint-presentation.html

Now export your presentation as video. :)